# Numbering theorems in the appendix by adding the appendix letter in front/after the theorem number

Tags: numbering, lyx, theorems, appendices

Can someone please tell me how to make definitions, theorems etc. in the appendix look like **Definition A1** or  **Definition 1A** (an "A" should be somewhere), if the appendix is "numbered" with **A** (meaning latex shows **A Appendix**, if I compile the document). Right now all the definitions, theorems etc.are numbered from 1 to n,  where n is the last definition, theorem etc. of my document (sections don't change the numbering), even if this last one is in the appendix.

Equation numbering is ok though; the first numbered equation is "A.1".

The thing is, I'm using LyX, so I would prefer it, if there were some command that I could use to reset the counter and globally change the look of  definitions, theorems etc. in the appendix, so that I

1) don't have to remove all the LyX-created environments (like for example the LyX-created definition environment) and replace them by hand-coded ones in order to maybe pass some additional arguments to each them, because that looks horrible in LyX.

2) don't have to use a different way to insert the appendix other then the one LyX provides and that is via  \appendix (not via the appendix package).

FYI: I'm using LyX 2; the document class is article; my appendix is situated after several sections (I don't used any other divisioning of my document like subsections etc. - if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following code to the preamble settings of your LyX document:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
```

In the document body, add the following "Evil Red Text" (LaTeX code) immediately after `\appendix` to effect the desired change for an environment called `thm`:

```
\counterwithin{thm}{section}
% \renewcommand{\thethm}{\thesection\arabic{thm}}% optional
```

You'll have to check your preamble for the existing theorem-like environments and their names (AFAIK, this depends on the loaded LyX modules) and apply the above code for *every* environment.

Here's a compilable example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{thm}
A theorem.
\end{thm}

\section{Second}

\begin{thm}
Another theorem.
\end{thm}

\appendix

\counterwithin{thm}{section}
% \renewcommand{\thethm}{\thesection\arabic{thm}}% optional

\section{App-First}

\begin{thm}
An appendix theorem.
\end{thm}

\section{App-Second}

\begin{thm}
Another appendix theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what if my appendix is called Appendix B, how to let the theorem display as Theorem B.1?